# Change launcher in AOSP 11

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

I am building AOSP 11 for emulator x86_64 and trying to change Default Launcher with third party launcher.

I am using raspberry pi's launcher [downloaded from here](https://github.com/android-rpi/RpLauncher/tree/arpi-11)

when I manually compile this launcher and install using adb It works, like it gives prompt to choose launcher.

but I need to add in source code.

I have found that I need to override default launcher.

So I have modified raspberry pi's launcher's Android.bp file

- add override section
- add system_ext_specific: true.( because this is default launcher's
  path.)

  ```
   android_app {
   name: "RpLauncher",
   overrides: ["Home Launcher2 Launcher3 Launcher3QuickStep"],
   platform_apis: true,
   certificate: "platform",
   privileged: true,
   system_ext_specific: true,

   static_libs: [
     "androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4",
     "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
     "androidx.leanback_leanback",
     "kotlinx-coroutines-core",
   ],

   srcs: ["src/**/*.kt"],
   resource_dirs: ["res"],
  ```

  }

Added package name "RpLauncher" in **build/target/product/handheld_system_ext.mk** where default launcher(Launcher3QuickStep) package added.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
Launcher3QuickStep \
Provision \
Settings \
StorageManager \
SystemUI \
WallpaperCropper \
RpLauncher \
```

After this when start the emulator only bootanimation appears and it never ends.
Anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here , Problem could be Device not booting as You are adding this app as privileged app

privileged: true,

So, You should whitelist the privileged permission requested by app

Like this https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Launcher3/Android.bp;l=170?q=Launcher3QuickStep&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

Comment: I have whitelist the privileged permission requested by app
By adding Following line in my case
required: ["privapp_whitelist_com.arpi.rplauncher"],, but same problem happens.

After that I tested wirh non  privileged app by removing privileged: true, line of Launcher's make file.
Now it works
@Ashok Mutyala

Comment: Can anyone please explain what is difference between privileged app and non privileged app ?.I Only know that Privileged apps that are located in a priv-app directory

Comment: ["privapp_whitelist_com.arpi.rplauncher"],, but same problem happens  -> Adding this line will not help, you should create like this https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/data/etc/Android.bp;l=120?q=privapp_whitelist_com.android.launcher3&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject    and  https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/data/etc/com.android.launcher3.xml?q=com.android.launcher3.xml&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

Answer (score 1):

@[Ashok Mutyala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10711264/ashok-mutyala), thanks for your help.Now I can add launcher as privileged app
Below are final changes

launcher's Android.bp

```
android_app {
name: "RpLauncher",
overrides: ["Home Launcher2 Launcher3 Launcher3QuickStep"],
platform_apis: true,
certificate: "platform",
privileged: true,
system_ext_specific: true,

static_libs: [
  "androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4",
  "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
  "androidx.leanback_leanback",
  "kotlinx-coroutines-core",
],

srcs: ["src/**/*.kt"],
resource_dirs: ["res"],
required: ["privapp_whitelist_com.arpi.rplauncher"],
```

}

create new file frameworks/base/data/etc/com.arpi.rplauncher.xml --> this is copy of frameworks/base/data/etc/com.android.launcher3.xml only change package name.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2019 The Android Open Source Project
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License
  -->
<permissions>
    <privapp-permissions package="com.arpi.rplauncher">
        <permission name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET"/>
        <permission name="android.permission.CONTROL_REMOTE_APP_TRANSITION_ANIMATIONS"/>
        <permission name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED"/>
        <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
    </privapp-permissions>
</permissions>
```

In frameworks/base/data/etc/Android.bp Add following.

```
prebuilt_etc {
    name: "privapp_whitelist_com.arpi.rplauncher",
    system_ext_specific: true,
    sub_dir: "permissions",
    src: "com.arpi.rplauncher.xml",
    filename_from_src: true,
}
```

Comment: @Margrish Thumar: do we need to copy apk file into aosp? .where to place the apk file ?

Comment: @Zappy.Mans If you are using apk file then put it in /system/priv-app/

Comment: @Margrish Thumar, what did you use ? you pull source code https://github.com/android-rpi/RpLauncher/tree/arpi-11 into RpLauncher folder or you put the apk file into that folder ?

Comment: @Zappy.Mans I have pulled the source code and build it in AOSP